# pandas picking timestamp every 15 mintues ,

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have dataframe in which first col1 is datestamp col2 is value , This data is of every 1 minute may be minute can escape in between of data . I have to pick only the 15 mintues interval data.i.e 00 , 15 , 30 45 mintues data dataframe.
How i can pick 15 mintues data.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_excel("Dhamra_May2020.xlsx")
dfwith15mintues=df[::15]# this is giving every 15 index number , which i dont want.
dfwith15mintues.to_csv("second_final_dhamra15mintues.csv",index=None,sep=",")
print(dfwith15mintues.head())
```

Comment: Please post your data as text so it can be copy-pasted easily.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to use `.loc` and only choose those times, where the minute-part of your time is in `[0, 15, 30, 45]`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = (pd.DataFrame({'t1': pd.date_range(start="2020-01-01 13:00 ", end="2020-01-01 14:00", freq="T"),
                    })
      )
df['sea_level'] = np.random.randint(2000, high=3000, size=df.shape[0])/1000

print(df.loc[df['t1'].dt.minute.isin([0, 15, 30, 45])])
```

resulting in

```
                    t1  sea_level
0  2020-01-01 13:00:00      2.712
15 2020-01-01 13:15:00      2.049
30 2020-01-01 13:30:00      2.889
45 2020-01-01 13:45:00      2.856
60 2020-01-01 14:00:00      2.571
```

Alternatively you could use the modulo function to find those values of the minute part which divide by 15 without remainder.

Writing the data to a file would then go with:
`df.loc[df['t1'].dt.minute.isin([0, 15, 30, 45])].to_excel("file.xlsx")`.